# Matrices Over finite fields.

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra

How Many nxn matrices over finite field Fq exists with full rank? explain.
I know there are q^n^2 matrices exists of order nxn over Fq.
But How to do this no idea...

Comment: If you show us what you have tried perhaps someone can use your work to provide a useful hint or complete answer.

Answer (score 2):

**Hint** The rows must be linearly independent.

The first row can be anything but $0$... How many choices do you have?

Second row can be anything but a scalar times first row... How many choices?

Third row can be anything but a scalar combination of the first two rows. How many choices do you have?

.......